# Laravel 5.2 High cpu with long routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I've setup a ubuntu 14.04 with php 5.5 and apache 2.4.

I installed a fresh laravel 5.2. No database connections in the project.

I then when to app/Http/routes.php and edited to:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::get('/test/direct', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

So basically I have 2 routes just showing the welcome view.

I then run:

```
ab -n 9999999 -t 300 -c 30 http://xxxxx/laravel52/public
```

The Cpu never goes over 6% and I get the following results:

```
Server Software:        Apache/2.4.7
Server Hostname:        xxxxx
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /laravel52/public
Document Length:        328 bytes

Concurrency Level:      30
Time taken for tests:   146.271 seconds
Complete requests:      50000
Failed requests:        0
Non-2xx responses:      50000
Total transferred:      28550000 bytes
HTML transferred:       16400000 bytes
Requests per second:    341.83 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       87.763 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       2.925 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          190.61 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       15   47  77.0     40    3157
Processing:    17   41  28.1     37    2140
Waiting:       17   40  26.9     37    2140
Total:         40   87  84.3     78    3208

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     78
  66%     83
  75%     86
  80%     89
  90%    100
  95%    120
  98%    162
  99%    228
 100%   3208 (longest request)
```

I then run:

```
ab -n 9999999 -t 300 -c 30 http://xxxxx/laravel52/public/test/direct
```

The Cpu immediately goes up to 100% and at the end I get these results:

```
Server Software:        Apache/2.4.7
Server Hostname:        xxxxx
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /laravel52/public/test/direct
Document Length:        1023 bytes

Concurrency Level:      30
Time taken for tests:   300.001 seconds
Complete requests:      11888
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      24585740 bytes
HTML transferred:       12161424 bytes
Requests per second:    39.63 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       757.070 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       25.236 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          80.03 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        4   12  29.4      8    1020
Processing:    75  740 790.0    609   14045
Waiting:       74  738 789.9    608   14043
Total:         88  752 789.4    622   14050

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    622
  66%    835
  75%    952
  80%   1020
  90%   1237
  95%   1536
  98%   2178
  99%   2901
 100%  14050 (longest request)
```

It seems that if it is not the root route laravel spikes the cpu if there are a lot of connections. This also happend with a fresh install in laravel 4.2.

Can anyone point out why this happens? I really need this solved.

My server has a 8 core Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4771 CPU @ 3.50GHz with 8GB of RAM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache your routes to speed up route resolution, but [route caching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#route-caching) does not work with Closure based routes. To use route caching, you must convert any Closure routes to use controller classes.

To cache your routes execute `php artisan route:cache` and to clear the cache `php artisan route:clear`.

You should also consider `php artisan optimize` to compile common classes in a single file, thus reducing the number of includes in each request, and `php artisan config:cache` to combines all the configuration file into a single file for faster loading.

Comment: Hi @Malta, It didn't solve the issue. It still remains. Created a controller with 1 method that return the welcome view. Mapped the 2 routes I had to 'TestController@showWelcome'. Ran `php artisan route::cache` and  `php artisan optimize`. Got more or less the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Forget this one. It is not a Laravel problem. It is a problem specific to this machine. A while back I upgraded ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. In doing so it upgraded apache 2.2 to 2.4 but kept part of the configuration. The problem should be there since other frameworks like Magento behave the same way.